# VIM colorscheme for Fortran and/or C++

Tags: vim, syntax-highlighting, vimdiff

I have recently changed my terminal colour to light (black letters on white background). As expected, this changed the way in which vim highlights the syntax profoundly. I managed to find some *.vim files for Fortran syntax highlighting, unfortunately, vimdiff (vi -d) still shows some rather poor performance. The colours form the syntax highlighting is not properly selected and it is very hard to read what is being highlighted by vimdiff itself.

I have seen some very nice colour schemes (vim/vimdiff) for both Fortran and c++ and I was hoping that I might get some help or someone might be willing to share his/hers *.vim files.

Thank you in advance

Comment: Have you tried `set background=light` in Vim?

Comment: Yes, I have tried it.

Answer (score -4):

Place in your `$VIMRUNTIME/colors` or `$HOME/vimfiles/colors`.

check this link

http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=1136